# Which jar file contains org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletWindow in websphere?

Tags: java, websphere, portlet

I am facing a code build issue in Rational application developer and it complains that it is not able to find org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletWindow class.

I found on google that this class is https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/portlet/5.0api/WPS/org/apache/jetspeed/portlet/PortletWindow.html

But I am not able to locate any jar which contains this class with the given package.

Can someone please help me on this? I have wesbphere 8.5 running on the server.

Comment: There is a PortletWindow class in WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 in com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar.
However, the fully qualified name is com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.om.window.PortletWindow

Comment: I found this class file in the following locations on the server


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/app/swh/wp61/PortalServer/doc/compile/public_api.jar
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/app/swh/wp61/PortalServer/doc/compile/public_spi.jar